# Is there any way to supress a ReSharper message for a class and its derived classes?

Tags: c#, resharper, code-analysis, custom-attributes

On a C# application, by using the `SupressMessage` attribute on a class like this:

```
[SuppressMessage("ReSharper", "UnassignedGetOnlyAutoProperty")]
```

I am able to suppress that type of message for the class, but it won't suppress it for its derived classes too.

Is there any way to achieve this?

I have tried to set the `Scope` and `Target` parameters in the `SupressMessage` attribute but no luck. Nothing mentioned in ReSharper documentation either.

Comment: Just curious, but why would you want an unassigned get only auto property in the first place?

Comment: That's a good question, I'd like to find out how to silence warnings on groups of related classes. On an unrelated note, how do you use an unassigned get-only auto property? Did you find a way to assign it through reflection?

Comment: The get-only auto property can be set only in the constructor or in the initialization assignment (I think this is new from C# 6.0). These only appear in my design-time view models (I am using WPF and PRISM), which for some of them I don't care, so I would like to supress it from all view models deriving from a common `DesignViewModel` abstract class.